# np.where check if columns are null

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write an np.where with a condition that looks to see if all columns except the first is null. I know how to filter the dataframe with this condition:

```
x[x.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(1)]
```

I would like to use this as a condition to say if all column values except the first are null, then change the value in column 1 to something.

```
x['col1'] = np.where(x[x.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(1)], 1, 0)
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the boolean condtion to `np.where`

```py
x['col1'] = np.where(x.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(1), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work :

```
x['col1'] = np.where(x.iloc[:, 1:].isna(), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check assign after you get the condition

```
colcond = x.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(1)

df.iloc[0, colcond] =  somevaluelist
```